# Redirecionamento para outra página na view do Django

Tags: python, django

estou aprendendo Django agora e a ideia é a seguinte:

Tenho um form de cadastro somente com o email, quando esse email for preenchido e o usuário clicar em enviar, preciso que a view direcione para a outra página onde o usuário irá terminar o cadastro, como faço?

(Da página /cadastro para a página /cadastro1)

Da maneira como está, eu consigo acessar o form cadastro1 pela url, porém quero que direcione sozinho quando for clicado em enviar[image: ![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGjbV.png)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

views.py

```
# coding: utf-8
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from portal.cadastro.forms import CadastroForm

def cadastro(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CadastroForm(request.POST)
    return render(request, 'cadastro.html',
                        {'form': CadastroForm()})


def cadastro1(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CadastroForm(request.POST)
    return render(request, 'cadastro1.html',
                        {'form': CadastroForm()})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ideia é que o código ao menos valide as informações inseridas no formulário, então fica mais ou menos assim:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)

        # Se as informações forem válidas
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            # Salva os dados contidos no formulário
            user.save()
            return redirect('/URL_PARA_SER_DIRECIONADO_APOS_O_SUBMIT/')

    else:
        form = RegisterForm()

    return render(request, 'register.html', {'register_form': form})
```

[Repositório do projeto](http://github.com/VictorAlessander/django-manager)

Me manda um feedback se a resposta solucionou o teu problema.

Comment: Oi Vitor, agradeço pela ajuda, funcionou sim, ele está redirecionando para a outra página como eu queria...

Comment: Porém o que preciso solucionar agora é o seguinte, o usuário preencheu o email e enviou, com isso redirecionou para a segunda parte do formulário, após preenchido, não está salvando no banco de dados nada...

Comment: @BiancaC. cria uma outra pergunta explicando o que foi feito e qual o novo problema, que aí fica mais fácil do que por aqui nos comentários :)